# Better export(PDF) profile format of Careers / Developer Story

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I'm testing the new Developer Story feature and it looks good, but though it is displayed nicely in the browser, when you export it in PDF is ugly and with the same format of the old Careers profile. 
The export should reflect the new Developer format profile.

Comment: Agreed, the PDF format works but I was honestly hoping for a little more when I head the Developer Story feature went live.

Comment: Disagree, I think the 'traditional' format works quite well for a CV.  The problem is that they seem to have removed the ability to control what actually gets exported.

Comment: The attraction of a developer story is it's cool layout and colors.  I want that to be represented to potential companies, but some of their hiring program still expect a PDF to parse information from and email around to internal employees for review. Since the PDF can only be generated in the legacy view I have potential blocker to use Developer Story all together.  I don't want this bland old looking PDF representing me, but I also don't want to create another version of my resume which I have to manually sync with the developer story which becomes to sources of truth.