# Export to PDF the CV page as any normal webpage

Tags: support, developer-story

> I need support for CV export to PDF feature.

When I print any page it prints with all its UI features, e.g. our blog prints **normally**:

[image: Blog]

which is the responsive view:

[image: Responsive blog]

Now, when I try to print [my CV](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/xameeramir)

[image: CV]

it takes some very old age form:

[image: CV print]

How do I export CV to PDF like any **normal** webpage taking into account its **normal** UI features?

Comment: I know there's a dupe like this floating around here somewhere, but this has been brought up before.  Basically, the export functionality uses the older view's page layout as opposed to the new page's layout.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320909/1079354

Comment: @Makoto Great! The main point is, is there a solution to this?